# Angular 4 how to filter group data in ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm building a project using Angular. I have set of sample data but I am not able to filter them using angular filters.

Here is the data:

```
issues = [
{'date': '12.01.2015', 
'text': [
    {'name': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'status': 'open' },
    {'name': 'Maecenas pellentesque', 'status': 'closed' }
]},
{'date': '12.04.2015', 
'text': [
    {'name': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'status': 'open' },
    {'name': 'Maecenas pellentesque', 'status': 'closed' },
    {'name': 'Fusce iaculis, purus fringilla', 'status': 'closed' }
]}
];
```

And I am doing ngFor twice to show date and later issues asigned to this date:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of issues">
<span class="item__date">{{group.date}}</span>
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let text of group.text">
    <div class="panel-body">{{text.name}}
        <span class="pull-right">{{text.status}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have buttons "all","open","closed". I want to switch the view to view only open and closed issues. I can actually list all issues:

```
return this.issues.slice();
```

But I am not able to use filtering to view only open or closed issues:

```
return this.issues.filter((issue) => {
    return issue.text.status === 'open';
});
```

This is giving me an error "Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ 'date': string; 'text': { 'name': string; 'status': string; }[]; }[]'."
Please give me a suggestion how to handle the filter to get only one type of issues, eg:

```
issues = [
{'date': '12.01.2015', 
'text': [
    {'name': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'status': 'open' },
]},
{'date': '12.04.2015', 
'text': [
    {'name': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'status': 'open' },
]}
];
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error doesn't match with the code you posted. Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: use <div *ngIf="text.status==variable || variable=='all' class="panel-body">...</div> and change the value of variable to 'open','close' or 'all' when you click the buttons